# Downgrading Magento Store

Tags: magento

What procedure should be followed to downgrade a Magento store from Enterprise Edition 1.10.1.1 to community Edition 1.7.0.0 ?

The steps I have done are:

1. Take backup of Magento EE 1.10.1.1 Database :)
2. Imported this Database in a blank one named database1.7
3. Used database1.7 to install MagentoCE  1.7.0.0

But while installing I am getting this error,

> 

### The page isn't redirecting properly.

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

- This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

> 

What exactly is wrong here ?

Comment: at what step of install?

Comment: @Tim : After I fill up the fields for connecting to database and continue the installation, but the next page( after a long wait ), gives the error message.

Comment: Try to do the following. Install 1.7 clean and then in app/etc/local.xml change the db name into your EE-based db.

Comment: If you do these steps you will not migrate any module. Should have a way to downgrade simply removing the enterprise stuff... I'm looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have copied `.htaccess` from your Enterprise installation into your CE root directory. If you unpack the CE archive you can grab a fresh `.htaccess` from there and copy it into your new CE root dir. If that does not work then follow Tim's advice on starting out with a fresh CE install first.